# Try to read a json file with python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that is a synonime dicitonnary in French (I say French because I had an error message with ascii encoding... due to the accents 'é',etc). I want to read this file with python to get a synonime when I input a word.
Well, I can't even read my file...
That's my code:

```
data=[]
with open('sortieDES.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
print(data)
```

So I have a list quite ugly, but my question is: how can I use the file like a dictionary ? I want to input `data['Académie']`and have the list of the synonime... Here an example of the json file:

```
{"Académie française":{
"synonymes":["Institut","Quai Conti","les Quarante"]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of

```
json.load(line)
```

you have to use

```
json.loads(line)
```

Your `s` is missing in `loads(...)`

Answer (score 2):

You only need to call json.load on the File object (you gave it the name data_file):

```
data=[]
with open('sortieDES.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
print(data)
```

Comment: When i do this i have this error: 'the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper''. I edited my post because my problem is different now :(

Comment: @pioupiou1211 are you using json.load or json.loads?  json.load takes a file object, which is what I demostrated above.  json.loads takes a string.

Comment: oh yeah my bad, seems that you resolved my problem! I have a nice dictionnary and i can do everything i want with it :) THanks a lot!